# When overriding change_form.html template in Django Admin, the breadcrumb for its model listview is grayed out and unclickable

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

For some reason when overriding the change_form.html template in Django Admin, its associated listview breadcrumb is grayed out and you can't click on it. Does anyone know how to make it available again? Thank you.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Can you link your html file?

Comment: Sure thing, will edit my previous post to include it.

Comment: Was too much code to post without more details. Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/devbaggett/pen/bJMgVM

Comment: Ok so you didn't change breadcrumbs, which means that `has_view_permission` returns False. Do you modify it anyhow?

Comment: Modify the breadcrumbs or the form? It does it with existing entries also.

Comment: I mean your new html file has the same breadcrumbs block as default, so model can be grayed out because admin method `has_view_permission` returns False. Check permissions of the user\group.

Comment: I'm on the superuser admin account. I even tried adding all the permissions and it was still grayed out. I can modify orders/promos all the same, it's just the breadcrumbs link I can't access, so I have to go back to the app list in order to access either orders/promos which is sort of a pain and an unnecessary step I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192089/discussion-between-gasanov-and-dev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that @Dev use django v1.11 and template is from django v.2.2.

In new template, django use `has_view_permission` to determine if user is able to access model page in admin panel. However, in django 1.11 there was no `view` permission and no `has_view_permission` method, thus it was rendered gray.

Comment: Just wanted to add, all I had to do to fix this was change 'has_view_permission' to 'has_change_permission'. Thanks again Gasanov!